# How to ignore some of filters on dashboard

Tags: gooddata

I would like to ask you, how is it possible to ignore some of filters on dashboard in the report? I know there exists a syntax construction WITHOUT PARENT FILTER, but it probably doesn't support EXCEPT keyword to allow keeping active some of filters.

Could you please give me an advice how to solve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you edit a "dashboard", you can click to edit properties "Report". One of these features is the "Filters" where you can select which dashboard filter will affect report and which does not.
[image]

Comment: Is it possible do something similar for metric? If I have two metrics in one row etc.?

Comment: You can create report specific metric with metric filter - select sum(fact) where attribute=value